# Porque me devuelve el listbox vacio?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

estoy haciendo un windows forms en el que tengo un listbox que va guardando los nombres de los ficheros acabados en .txt y eso lo voy haciendo con un timer que va comprobando cada rato si hay un fichero nuevo para añadir o no ya que cuento con otro programa que va generando estos archivos. Pero al hacer el timer eso me lo hace correctamente, pero cuando intento mostrar el primer nombre que ha guardado en el listbox me salta este error :

> ```
> >     System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=El valor de '0' no es válido para 'index'.
> >     Nombre del parámetro: index'
> ```

El error ocurre justo en la linea: `tbPrueba.Text = listaFicheros.Items[0].ToString();`

Es como que lo recibe vacio, pero debugando en la función si que esta pillando y guardando los nombres en la lista y en el forms aparece los nombres, este es el código que tengo :

```
    private string buscar = "*.txt";
    private string fileName = ""; 
    private string destFile = ""; 
    private string ruta = "c:\\Textos";
    private string rutaProcesante = "c:\\Textos\\Processant";
    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        iniTimer();
        tbPrueba.Text = listaFicheros.Items[0].ToString(); //AQUI JUSTO SALTA EL ERROR 

    }

    private void iniTimer()
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ficheros = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, buscar);
        foreach (string s in ficheros)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
            destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(rutaProcesante, fileName);
            listaFicheros.Items.Add(fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si esta cargado, pero despues de cuando lo estas pasando a tbPrueba.Text... fiajte el orden de carga y el orden de las cosas que haces...

Answer (score 1):

Te devuelve el listBox vacío, porque realmente esta vacío. Si te fijas, listaFicheros se llena con el timer, al timer lo habilitas en el evento Load y el evento load se llama cuando abrís el formulario.
Es normal que este vacío ya que recién esta creado, si lo que intentas hacer, es siempre tener una lista de ficheros y que te cargue el primero en esa ventana, vas a tener que sacar ese método y ponerlo en otra clase y hacerla global o ponerla en un formulario padre que llame a este formulario.
Asumiendo que sacas el iniciado del timer y la carga de la lista de este formulario y lo colocas en otra clase, tu evento load debería ser así.

```
private string buscar = "*.txt";
private string fileName = ""; 
private string destFile = ""; 
private string ruta = "c:\\Textos";
private string rutaProcesante = "c:\\Textos\\Processant";
string[] ficheros = null;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cargarDatos();
    if listaFicheros.Items.Count > 0 //valida que la lista tenga cargada por lo menos una ruta
      tbPrueba.Text = listaFicheros.Items[0].ToString(); 
    iniTimer();
}

private void iniTimer()
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cargarDatos();
}

private void cargarDatos()
{
    if(ficheros = null)
    {
        ficheros = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, buscar);
        foreach (string s in ficheros)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
            destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(rutaProcesante, fileName);
            listaFicheros.Items.Add(fileName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string s in ficheros)
        {
            fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
            destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(rutaProcesante, fileName);
            listaFicheros.Items.Add(fileName);
        }
    }       
}
```

proba con este codigo y decime si te tira algun error.

Comment: Entonces si por ejemplo quiero pasarle el listbox entero a una clase como : lista.Add(new ClLector(this,listaFicheros, new Point(this.Width-500, (130*i)))); Deberia de comprobar con un if antes si contiene algún elemento como dijiste no ?

Comment: Me piden que tiene que ser todo en el mismo formulario, no crear de otras clases y que se ejecute en otro lado

Comment: De ser asi, entonces vas a tener que crear un metodo que se llame algo asi como cargarDatosAlInicio() y poner la misma logica que tiene el timer1_Tick. Despues de eso, llama a este metodo en el constructor del formulario o en el load (si es en el load, hacelo en la primera linea antes que todo). El if dejalo por las dudas no exista ninguna ruta. Ya edito la respuesta para mostrarte como seria.